# How to properly run multiple nodejs app using PM2 on EC2?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, pm2

On my EC2 I am deploying 2 nodejs apps.

What I am doing before is creating a multiple screen and run the npm run start.

Now I am trying to use the PM2, I installed it inside the ec2 and tried the following start command:

```
pm2 start --name "APP_NAME" npm -- start
```

The process runs but i do not think it was what im expecting.
here is my run script inside *package.json*

```
"start": "env-cmd -f ./config/app.env node index.js"
```

I also tried adding adding pm2 start inside the *package.json* but fails as expected.

This is my first time trying the PM2 so I'm quite lost right now.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first create a file  ecosystem.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [
      {
        name: "myapp",
        script: "./app.js",
        watch: true,
        env: {
            "PORT": 3000,
            "NODE_ENV": "development"
        },
        env_production: {
            "PORT": 80,
            "NODE_ENV": "production",
        }
      }
  ]
}
```

after that you can run it like this :

```
pm2 start ecosystem.conf.js
```

for handling the [logs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2-logrotate) :

```
npm i pm2-logrotate
```

or

```
pm2 install pm2-logrotate
```

after that you have to add pm2 as a service in your host.

```
pm2 startup
```

after all the configuration and checking the pm2 apps with :

```
pm2 status <instance number> 
pm2 logs
```

you can save your current configuration in pm2 with :

```
pm2 save
```

more details about pm2 [startup](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/)

Comment: after few tries finally understand it. thanks